# Using Google App Engine NDB and Fixture(s)

Tags: google-app-engine, fixtures, fixture, app-engine-ndb

Is there good information on how to use the Python [fixture](http://farmdev.com/projects/fixture/) module with Google App Engines [New DB](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/)?

It seems there are a few problems, such as:

1. `obj.delete()` on teardown (in `ndb` it's `obj.key.delete()`)
2. It is not intuitive how to set up nested [StructuredProperty](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#structured) elements.

Are there workarounds to permit the Fixture module to work with `ndb`, or an alternative fixture system that would work with `ndb`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that fixture's GoogleDatastoreFixture class intercepts the Datastore operations at the ext.db module level. Since NDB has a different API it needs changing. Perhaps you can contribute a GoogleNdbFixture class. Or perhaps the right thing to do would be to intercept things at a lower level -- again, something you might take up with fixture's author and see if there's a way you can help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider using [Testbed](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting)? It setups GAE service stubs appropriately, so you can test against datastore (and other services) and it will tear down all your datastore writes after each test.

To create fixtures for your tests, you just directly put some entities into datastore in `setUp()` method. And you can use NDB API to put fixtures and in tests if you like.

Comment: Thanks @Maxim. I am using Testbed, but creating fixtures through `setUp()` is not as elegant as the Fixtures package. I would like to use both.